# How can i create an app for Samsung smart tv Remote in iOS programming?

Tags: ios, samsung-smart-tv, remote-control, live-connect-sdk, smartview

I need to create a remote control app in ios for samsung tvs. I did google too but i can not able to get exact solution. I have seen this SDK link
    https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/smart-view-sdk/sender-apps/ios-sender-app
But is it still allowing me to connect latest tv models also ?

I have seen codes provided in github but none of them are working for me.
    https://github.com/SamsungDForum/SmartViewSDKIntegrateSample

I have also seen that there is TIZEN platform to do it but i am not aware with that also.
I am still confused that is its control code need to write in swift or objective c or it will be done via web APIS? because i have seen node.js reference as well for this.

```
https://github.com/Toxblh/samsung-tv-control
https://github.com/piu130/samsung-tv-remote-interface
https://github.com/piu130/samsung-tv-remote-interface-keys
```

I have seen smartthings link too but it also not giving me any hint from which i can start.
    https://smartthings.github.io/

However i have seen there are many apps available to operate samsung tvs. I wonder how they did the connection and operate the remote keys ?

I have seen http://connectsdk.com/. And this is available in objective c and working for LG tv. I have tried and tested in lg tv but it is not working in samsung tv.

Thank you.

Comment: TLDR; Does Samsung Tizen OS have an input control API?Any sample iOS implementations?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a samsung remote easily using websockets. Take a look at this project.
https://github.com/Ape/samsungctl

The code is in python and it contains two methods.

1. Websockets
2. Legacy

I prefer to use websockets and it is actually quite easy. By looking at the websockets section in this project you will get an idea of how to use websockets to connect to samsung TV and control it by sending commands.

Comment: web sockets not working the connection is refused. the same issue was reported on GitHub too but there was any response from the developer side.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Samsung remote easily using WebSockets.
It's Quite Easy to work with this Library, Only need some basic knowledge about Socket.

**https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream**

without needing any Server Side Support.